# SQL for Multiple Account names - MYOB

Tags: sql, myob

This is what i have got so far.

`A.ACCGROUP=1`

This works to show only accounts in region #1. but i would like to be able to see regions #1, 12 & 18 at the same time.
This is for the custom filters within MYOB accounting software.

Is this possible, Thank you in advance

I have tried `A.ACCGROUP='1' AND '12'` but got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
A.ACCGROUP IN (1, 12, 18)
```

Comment: Thank You - that was very fast.